# multiple commands line in VS Code without open a new window

Tags: javascript, command-line, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make multiple command lines in VS Code without open a new window. Someone knows how to do that ?

Here the failing codes I have tried so far :

```
touch foo.js & code -a  #!:1

touch foo.js && code -a  #!:1
```

these command line entries open a new window, however I would open a new tab in the same VS Code session,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [PR 45322](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/45322), check if your setting `window.openWithoutArgumentsInNewWindow` is set to '`on`'.

That controls if a new empty window should open when starting a second instance without arguments or if the last running instance should get focus.

Set it to off. Then try again `code aFile`.